# Factorization involving degree 4

Tags: factoring

What are the factors of: 
$$81a^4 +(x-2a)(x-5a)(x-8a)(x-11a)$$

Do I need to solve $(x-2a)(x-5a)(x-8a)(x-11a)$? If yes, is there a better way to do it? I would be grateful if someone offered hints to tackle this problem rather than the whole solution because I really want to solve it myself.

Thank you.

Comment: If by solving $(x−2a)(x−5a)(x−8a)(x−11a)$ you mean expanding all brackets, then answer is yes, you can avoid it (see my answer for few hints).

Comment: When you have factors $x-r_1,x-r_2,x-r_3,x-r_4$ that form an arithmetic progression, then $r_1+r_4=r_2+r_3$. This means that if you multiply $(x-r_1)(x-r_4)=x^2-(r_1+r_4)+r_1r_4$ and $(x-r_2)(x-r_3)=x^2-(r_2+r_3)+r_2r_3$, the part $y=x^2-(r_1+r_4)=x^2-(r_2+r_3)$. This means that you get a polynomial of half the degree in $y$, since $(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)(x-r_4)=(y-r_1r_4)(y-r_2r_3)$. Then you can use the quadratic formula to factor this into two linear factors in $y$. Then replace the $y$ back to the variable $x$ and factor the two quadratics that appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x^2-13ax=y,$

We have $(y-22a^2)(y-40a^2)+81a^4=y^2-2y(31a^2)+(31a^2)^2=?$

Answer (score 2):

I would expand all the brackets. Then the coefficient of $a^4$ is $961=31^2$, which hints at the factorization $(x^2\pm 31a^2+cax)(x^2\pm 31a^2+dax)$, $c,d\in\mathbb{R}$. Find $c$ and $d$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint(s):**

You are supposed to exploit the symmetry of the equation.  Notice that each bracket on right differs by $3a$, so choosing the right substitution $x \mapsto x+k\cdot a$ (can you deduce what $k$ to use?) will make them align nicely as $$\left(x+\frac{9a}{2}\right)\left(x+\frac{3a}{2}\right)\left(x-\frac{3a}{2}\right)\left(x-\frac{9a}{2}\right).$$ Then notice also that $81a^4=(3a)^4$. Also $c^2-d^2=(c-d)(c+d)$ is quite handy in this problem. Can you use these hints to solve the problem by yourself?